# Dozer file not found exception

Tags: dozer

I am trying to execute below dozer example. my xml file is located in the same location as my java file, but i am getting the file not found exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.dozer.MappingException: Unable to locate dozer mapping file [dozerMapping.xml] in the classpath!
    at org.dozer.util.MappingUtils.throwMappingException(MappingUtils.java:87)
    at org.dozer.util.MappingValidator.validateURL(MappingValidator.java:63)
    at org.dozer.loader.CustomMappingsLoader.loadFromFiles(CustomMappingsLoader.java:101)
    at org.dozer.loader.CustomMappingsLoader.load(CustomMappingsLoader.java:56)
    at org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper.loadCustomMappings(DozerBeanMapper.java:213)
    at org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper.getMappingProcessor(DozerBeanMapper.java:186)
    at org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper.map(DozerBeanMapper.java:111)
    at com.mapping.CopyAttributes.main(CopyAttributes.java:28)
```

If i give the complete the file path it is working but i am getting the below exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.dozer.MappingException: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c
    at org.dozer.util.MappingUtils.throwMappingException(MappingUtils.java:82)
    at org.dozer.util.ResourceLoader.getResource(ResourceLoader.java:57)
    at org.dozer.util.DefaultClassLoader.loadResource(DefaultClassLoader.java:44)
    at org.dozer.util.MappingValidator.validateURL(MappingValidator.java:61)
    at org.dozer.loader.CustomMappingsLoader.loadFromFiles(CustomMappingsLoader.java:101)
    at org.dozer.loader.CustomMappingsLoader.load(CustomMappingsLoader.java:56)
    at org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper.loadCustomMappings(DozerBeanMapper.java:213)
    at org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper.getMappingProcessor(DozerBeanMapper.java:186)
    at org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper.map(DozerBeanMapper.java:111)
    at com.mapping.CopyAttributes.main(CopyAttributes.java:28)
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.dozer.util.ResourceLoader.getResource(ResourceLoader.java:55)
```

**source code**

```
    String file = "C:/UnitTest/Dozer/src/com/mapping/mapping.xml";
    DozerBeanMapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper(Arrays.asList(new String[]{file}));
```

Answer (score 7):

Ok. I solved this..

I put the file in `resources/META-INF/dozerBeanMapping.xml` and accessed the file by using:

```
String file = "META-INF/dozerBeanMapping.xml";

DozerBeanMapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper(Arrays.asList(new String[]{file}));
```

I hope this will help you guys as well.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `String file = "C:/..."` and the error mentions it doesn't recognize C as a valid protocol.

You should try using `file://C:/...` instead - it may help. If that doesn't, try using double backslashes (`C:\\UnitTest\\...`) and if that doesn't work just upload the file somewhere

Comment: I really doubt that you are getting a "unknown protocol: c" error when you use a file:// URL.

Comment: It worked with little correction with forward slashes instead of backward slashes.     String file = "file:\\C:\\temp\\mapping.xml";
  DozerBeanMapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper(Arrays.asList(new String[]{file}));
  TargetEmployee destObject = mapper.map(sourceEmp, TargetEmployee.class);

Comment: Those are backward slashes mate :-)

Comment: :-) i know but it worked with file:\\C:\\ not with file://C://